# Get Alert when a new user is added in O365 Admin

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I have been searching but cannot find a way to set an alert for when a user is added to O365 Admin. Earlier there was an alert policy which allowed choosing User Administrator's actions. However now that option is there no more.

This [ans](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/alert-for-new-added-user/m-p/2650614) suggests using legacy activity alerts, however, it takes me to the same new page where I do not have the option of choosing those activities.

Writing some script to get this information periodically from Graph API is not practical and doesn't address the issue. This is one of the other methods that was suggested.

Any suggestions on how best to achieve this?

Comment: What tier of Azure AD do you have? P1 or P2? Does your licensing include Sentinel?

Comment: @SamErde Premium P1..No, it doesn't include Sentinel, needs to purchased separately.

Comment: Are you asking for an alert when a new user is created in the console?  Or a new user is granted admin roles in O365?

Comment: @TheCleaner An alert, via email, when a new user is added/updated/deleted. Not when granted Admin role.

Comment: @AbhishekRai - one thing you could do is use this script: http://woshub.com/get-user-group-creation-date-azure-powershell/ that could run every 10 minutes and look for users created in the last 10 minutes and email that info...beyond that I'm not sure.

Comment: @TheCleaner I am aware of this. However this is not practical in our case. Strange that microsoft removed User admin's activties from Alert policies. :(

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be possible in the legacy "Activity Alerts" page:

https://compliance.microsoft.com/managealerts

You can configure a "New alert policy" which can generate emails for when any one performs the activity of "Added user". Once configured, as soon as a   new user is added to Azure AD & Office 365, you will get an email. It looks as though you could also use the activity of "Added member to Role" for notifications.